# SPARK Application + HDFS + User Airflow is not the owner of inode=alapati

Tags: apache-spark, hadoop, hdfs, airflow, hdp

We are running spark application on Hadoop cluster ( HDP version - 2.6.5 from Hortonworks ).

From the logs we can see the following Diagnostics

```
User: airflow
Application Type: SPARK
User class threw exception: org.apache.hadoop.security.AccessControlException: Permission denied. user=airflow is not the owner of inode=alapati
```

It is not provided clearly in log what we need to search in `HDFS` in order to find why we get Permission denied.

Comment: What is alapati? Is that a user? Can you add airflow user to the hdfs user group on the namenode?

Comment: can you give example how to  add airflow user to the hdfs user group on the namenode

Comment: Lookup examples of `groupadd` and `useradd`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks line user=airflow don't have access to write data into HDFS.

By default the /user/ directory is owned by "hdfs" with 755 permissions. As a result only hdfs can write to that directory.

You can use two options:

1. change spark user name from **airflow** to **hdfs** or
2. If you still need to use user=airflow, create a home directory for airflow

sudo -u hdfs hadoop fs -mkdir /user/airflow
sudo -u hdfs hadoop fs -chown root /user/airflow

Comment: about step 2 - by default - /user/airflow is with airflow:hdfs , do you means to change to root:hdfs?

Comment: The issue is with node of the name alapati, not airflow

Comment: but I not see any user as alapati ( I checked as  grep  alapati /etc/passwd )

Comment: check the hdfs user group, create the user=airflow with same group and start the application